# How to activate action sheet buttons with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, ios5

I am looking for a way to link the buttons of the action sheet functional for the user

i made the Delete button functional but i need for the Report button making the user be able to send E-mail, how to do that with swift? Thank you

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var ReportAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Report User", handler: {(action: UITableViewRowAction! , indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let ReportMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Report using", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        let Reportbutton = UIAlertAction(title: "E-Mail", style: .Default , handler: nil)

        ReportMenu.addAction(Reportbutton)
        self.presentViewController(ReportMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)


    })

        var DeleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default , title: "Delete", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

            self.Array1.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.Array2.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.Array3.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.Array4.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.Array5.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)


            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    }
    )
    return [DeleteButton , ReportAction]



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let Reportbutton = UIAlertAction(title: "E-Mail", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in

            //Your code
        }
```

Here is the example code for you to send E-mail:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

var tabledata = ["1","2","3","4"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return tabledata.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = tabledata[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var ReportAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Report User", handler: {(action: UITableViewRowAction! , indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let ReportMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Report using", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        let Reportbutton = UIAlertAction(title: "E-Mail", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in

            self.displayMailComposerSheet()
        }
        ReportMenu.addAction(Reportbutton)
        self.presentViewController(ReportMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)


    })

    var DeleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default , title: "Delete", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        self.tabledata.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)



        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        }
    )
    return [DeleteButton , ReportAction]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:

        // remove the deleted item from the model
        self.tabledata.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func displayMailComposerSheet(){

    //vars
    var controller = MFMailComposeViewController()
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self

    //set
    controller.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    //set
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    var attributes = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)!,NSFontAttributeName, UIColor.whiteColor(), NSForegroundColorAttributeName)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes

    //set
    var toRecipients = NSArray(object: "support@YourDomain.com")
    controller.setToRecipients(toRecipients)
    controller.setSubject("App Support")

    //show
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.Default, animated: true)
    })
    }
}
```

Comment: yup it is the right answer and also to dismiss the Mail composer add this code
    func mailComposeController(controller:     MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result:    MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }